# Can't access Dingo Api routes in localhost

Tags: laravel, routes, localhost, dingo-api, laragon

I have my laravel project created inside laragon/www folder and I'm using dingo/api package for routing.

Here are my files

routes/web.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

routes/api.php

```
<?php
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Router;
$api->get('test', 'TestController@index');
```

app/Http/Controllers/Api/TestController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
class TestController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

When I run artisan api/routes it gives me the URI api/test but when I try to reach it in my browser under http://localhost/myproject/public/api/test it returns error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found" knowing that http://localhost/myproject/public/ returns the good result

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->get('test', 'TestController@index');
```

Comment: no changes, I am getting always the same error message

Comment: I think that issue come from the url I am enterring in my browser, have you any other suggestion ?

Comment: @user7350434 try http://localhost/myproject/public/test , http://localhost/myproject/public/api/v1/test , etc.

Comment: @user7350434 try this $api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {
    $api->get('test', 'TestController@index');
});

**url: localhost/myproject/public/api/v1/test or http://localhost/myproject/public/api/v1/test**

Comment: @user7350434 Check the API_DOMAIN= setting in config/api.php or if you are setting in .env file

Comment: And what should I put for this key?